# I've seen many CSS compatibility list for browsers, Is there any list for X/HTML tag? or all browsers supports all tags?

Tags: xhtml, html

I've seen many CSS compatibility list for browsers, Is there any list for X/HTML tag? or all browsers supports all tags?

Is there any list for all major browser's supported HTML, XHTML and HTML 5 supported TAGS?

Answer (score 1):

The validity of the tags you use will depend on your doctype and the browser/version you're using.

- XHTML 1.0 Strict Reference - http://www.december.com/html/x1/
- XHTML 1.0 Transitional Reference - http://www.december.com/html/x1tran/
- HTML 4.01 Transitional Reference - http://www.december.com/html/4loose/
- HTML 4.01 Strict Reference - http://www.december.com/html/4/

--

- HTML 4 Spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/
- HTML 4.01 Spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/
- HTML 5 Spec - http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

#### See Also:

- [Comparison of Layout Engines (HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5))

Comment: I know about all i'm not asking about just list of html elements. Can we enable support for any alement in browser using doctype? my question is not realted to doctype

Comment: Jitendra, your question **is** related to the doctype.

Comment: Can doctype enable support for any element in browser if internet connection is not available?

Comment: Jitendra, that's dependent upon the browser you're using.

Answer (score 1):

That purely depends on the [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) used. If you define a doctype which is unknown to the webbrowser, then it can in theory just download the DTD from the specified URL itselves and apply it on the elements.

For standard DTD's you can just check  here at the [w3schools (X)HTML reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp) which (X)HTML elements are supported.

If you define *no* doctype, the browser will trigger to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) (and you don't want to have that).

Comment: if internet connection not available then? and HTML 5 doctype doesn't have any DTD url.

Comment: If internet is down, the browser will go quirksmode in case of an unknown/uncached doctype. The HTML5 doctype is handled like HTML4 Strict, but not all HTML5 elements are supported by all browsers yet (only Opera does), but it is supposedly to be builtin in future webbrowsers.